# Installing `transformers` on HPC Cluster

Tags: pip, centos, hpc, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to install the transformers library on HPC. I do:

```
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
cd transformers
pip install -e . --user
```

All three of these work as expected, with the last output being:

```
Successfully installed dataclasses-0.7 numpy-1.19.0 tokenizers-0.8.1rc2 transformers
```

Then, I try `python -c "import transformers"` but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/maths/btech/mt1170727/transformers/src/transformers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .configuration_albert import ALBERT_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP, AlbertConfig
  File "/home/maths/btech/mt1170727/transformers/src/transformers/configuration_albert.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .configuration_utils import PretrainedConfig
  File "/home/maths/btech/mt1170727/transformers/src/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .file_utils import CONFIG_NAME, cached_path, hf_bucket_url, is_remote_url
  File "/home/maths/btech/mt1170727/transformers/src/transformers/file_utils.py", line 37, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/home/soft/PYTHON/3.6.0/ucs4/gnu/447/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/home/soft/PYTHON/3.6.0/ucs4/gnu/447/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 83, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/home/soft/PYTHON/3.6.0/ucs4/gnu/447/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 344, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libnvToolsExt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have done as was written in the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/installation.html#installing-from-source), and can't see why I'm facing this error. Any help would be great. Thanks...

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: @cronoik CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but have you installed the package which provides libnvToolsExt.so.1 probably [this](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/cuda-libs-7.5.18-3.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html)?

Comment: @cronoik no, I don't have any `/usr/lib64/libnvToolsExt.so.1`. But I can't install it bcoz i don't have sudo privileges. Any idea should I do?

Comment: I have no experience with centos and can't help you without some research. Maybe someone on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/) can help you.